# Positioning titles and img

Tags: html, css, web, css-position

How do I position "mean design" to be on top of the logo and the description below the logo? the whole thing should be center vertically and horizontally

It looks like this  now
[image]

Heres the code now

```css
.title {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover-wrapper">
            <div class="title">
            <h1 id="mean">Mean Design.</h1>
            <img class="img-responsive" id="logo" src="MeanDesignLogo.png">
            <h6 id="des">ui/ux • web design • graphic design • illustration</h6>
                </div>
</div> <!-- cover wrapper -->
```

Comment: what is your problem? i thing you have done that, just change the font color and see. https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=9fg9wF2xQi

Comment: @Charles_R See the edited question, thanks

Comment: try this, put  **display: block;** for each element

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get something like this ?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.title {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-image:url(MeanDesignLogo.png); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%
}

.title2 {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
    top: 449px;
    left: 592px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 350px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="cover-wrapper">
  <div class="title">
            <h1 id="mean">Mean Design.</h1>
 <h6 id="des"></h6>
  </div>
  <div class="title2">
    <h6 id="des">ui/ux • web design • graphic design • illustration</h6>
  </div>
</div> <!-- cover wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have to remove all the css in `#logo`:

```css
.title {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    color: black;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="cover-wrapper">
            <div class="title">
            <h1 id="mean">Mean Design.</h1>
            <img class="img-responsive" id="logo" src="http://placehold.it/200x50?text=LOGO">
            <h6 id="des">ui/ux • web design • graphic design • illustration</h6>
                </div>
</div> <!-- cover wrapper -->
```